# How to authenticate via email rather than username in passport.js?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am currently using this code for logging in:

```
passport.use(new localStrategy({
  usernameField: 'username'
}, User.authenticate()));
```

That works fine when I login with username and password.
Now I want to login with email rather than username.
I've changed my code to this:

```
passport.use(new localStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  usernameQueryFields: ['email']
}, User.authenticate()));
```

I've also changed my HTML code to display email field with the name of email:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control">
```

and here's my users' schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("585f62d63158ec1f608f82a2"),
    "salt" : "d7fd24ab337be7341bb6c54df69eccdce607a6cffc8457be4d44",
    "hash" : "(long text)",
    "username" : "joseph320",
    "email" : "joseph@gmail.co",
    "name" : "joseph",
    "__v" : 0,
}
```

So now it should look for email field in database and compare that with the email user provided in login form. But it doesn't work. When I try to login with email and password it gives me 'invalid username or password' error.

But when I am try to login with the username and the exact password it will successfully log me in.
Where is the problem and how can I solve the problem?

I am using this packages for authentication:

```
"passport": "^0.3.2",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"passport-local-authenticate": "^1.2.0",
"passport-local-mongoose": "^4.0.0",
```

Comment: I am playing around with the code and looks like that the problem is from 'usernameQueryFields'. It does not look for email field in database. But still I cannot solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

From what I understand, you need to tell `passport-local-mongoose` which field to use:

```
User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField : 'email' });
```

([doc](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose#options))

And also use it to create the strategy for you:

```
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
```

([doc](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose#simplified-passportpassport-local-configuration))

Comment: I have a problem with this command and I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944290/how-to-use-mongoose-schemas-and-passport-with-nodejs-es6typescript

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with this one for a bit.  It's important that you have the `usernameField` defined in **TWO** places:

1. When creating your `localStrategy` (as in Joseph's original question):

   ```
   passport.use(new localStrategy({
       usernameField: 'email'
   }, User.authenticate()));
   ```
2. When defining your user model (as in robertklep's answer):

   ```
   userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose,
   {
       usernameField: 'email'
   });
   ```

Comment:  Amazing - thank you! 

I brushed over your response the first time and thought it was either/or. It works perfectly when added in two places. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

By default, LocalStrategy expects to find credentials in parameters named username and password. If your site prefers to name these fields differently, options are available to change the defaults.

Read [more](http://passportjs.org/docs):

```
passport.use(
        'local-signup',
        new LocalStrategy({

            usernameField : 'email',

            passwordField : 'password',

            passReqToCallback : true 
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {

            User.findOne({email: username}, function(err, user) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (!user) {
                     return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
                 }
                if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                     return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                }
                return done(null, user);
            })

        })
)
```

Comment: // do some stuff!! there is my real problem. what should I write there?

Comment: If you set `passReqToCallback` to `true`, make sure that the callback function actually accounts for the additional `req` argument.

Comment: 2 things: 1- it search for a user where email equals to username? or is the username the provided email? 2- My biggest problem is exactly validPassword function. I do not know how to validate the password. There is hash and salt in database, how can I validate it?

Comment: 1 - It search for email field in your mongodb. 2-  Validate the password readmore here http://danialk.github.io/blog/2013/02/23/authentication-using-passportjs/